# UV map disappears when I re-upload the mesh

Tags: uv

When I try to sync the mesh by 3dm.import addon, the all UV maps gone. Is there a solution for that?

It stores in mesh data. But How can i copy previous mesh data UV map to new one?

The UV map and material stays but the size and scale (unwrap settings) are gone

[image]

[image]

[image]